# NSOpenPanel display issues

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I'm using `NSOpenPanel` to allow the user to select a file. However, the UI of `NSOpenPanel` sometimes plays up. The sidebar sometimes is shown, sometimes it isn't. The selected folder (in this case, "Cookie Stumbler") can be moved to the middle/bottom/wherever of the open panel simply by scrolling and sometimes it stalls the entire application.

I am calling the `NSOpenPanel` as part of an `IBAction` using the **main** thread. Nothing is logged in `Console.app`, though I remember it logging something once along the lines of "waiting for UI to respond".

Here's how the `NSOpenPanel` is setup:

```
NSOpenPanel*open = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

[open setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Select License File",nil)];
[open setPrompt:NSLocalizedString(@"Select License",nil)];
[open setMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"Please select your Cookie Stumbler license file:",nil)];
[open setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"cskey"]];

[open beginSheetModalForWindow:_registrationWindow completionHandler:^(NSInteger result)
{
    if (result == NSOKButton)
    {
         // other code here
    }
}];
```

What's going on?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a break point set in Xcode? I get the behavior that you see if I do, but not if I don't (or if I check "automatically continue after evaluating").  I noticed that the exception is happening on a thread that's labeled "quicklook.pluginload" This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me too. I do have break points on during debugging, but never for release. I might have forgotten to switch them off this time, so I'll check when I get to my Mac later. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't have breakpoints enabled unfortunately. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'll post a rdar. Let's see what they can do.

Comment: You may need a new run loop for it.

Comment: I have the same problem, how do you fixed it?

Comment: I wasn't able to - this was an internal problem according to the logs.